# Static Method Access in Factory Pattern

Tags: python, oop, factory

I have some problems on Factory Pattern in Python. I do not know how to use Base Class (BaseGeometryShape) 'name' property in Factory Class (ShapeFactory).

Here is my code:

```
import abc, sys
from typing import List

PI = 3.14

class Shape(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """
    Class that defines methods for all shapes
    """
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_perimeter(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_area(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __str__(self):
        pass


class Polygon(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """
    Class that defines methods for polygon shapes
    """
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_angles(self):
        pass


class BaseGeometryShape:
    """
    Base class for geometry objects
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class ShapeFactory(BaseGeometryShape):
    def __init__(self, name):
        BaseGeometryShape.__init__(self, name)
    
    @staticmethod
    def create_shape(shape: str, params: List[str]):
        # TODO
        pass


def get_info(shape: str, params: List[str]):
    shape = ShapeFactory.create_shape(shape, params)
    info = shape.name + '\n'
    if isinstance(shape, Shape):
        info += 'Perimeter is: {:.2f}\n'.format(shape.get_perimeter())
        info += 'Area is: {:.2f}\n'.format(shape.get_area())

    if isinstance(shape, Polygon):
        info += 'Number of angles: {}\n'.format(shape.get_angles())

    return info

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin:        
        line = line.strip()

        params = line.split(' ')
        shape = params[0]
        if len(params) == 2:
            info = get_info(shape, params[1].split(','))
        else:
            info = get_info(shape, [])

        print(info)
```

I always get an error like this when I run the program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "factory.py", line 74, in <module>
    info = get_info(shape, params[1].split(','))
  File "factory.py", line 52, in get_info
    info = shape.name + '\n'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I already searched the internet on how to use Base Class in Factory Class, but I cannot find anything

Thank You

Comment: The current code should not exhibit that error. Please show the code you used to get that error.

Comment: I revised my code. I need to do something with the todo part. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Your `ShapeFactory` subclasses `BaseGeometry`, which is not defined in the snippet you posted. Can you add that please?

Comment: Sorry, it's miswritten, it should be BaseGeometryShape, the class above ShapeFactory